# Modify request header in middleware

Tags: go, middleware

Hopefully, this is an easy way to earn some rep. This seems very simple, so I must be doing something wrong and just cant see it.

I have a simple middleware which a transaction id and adds it to the request and response headers.

```
    func HandleTransactionID(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        tid := uuid.NewV4()
        req.Header.Set(TransIDHeader, TransIDPrefix + tid.String())
        w.Header().Set(TransIDHeader, TransIDPrefix + tid.String())
        fn(w, req)
    }
}
```

In my unit tests, I've confirmed the response header is successfully set, but it doesn't appear the the request header is being set. I would assume that it is possible to modify the request headers, so ?

```
const (
    WriteTestHeader = "WriterTransHeader"
    RequestTestHeader = "ReqTransHeader"
)


func recorderFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set(WriteTestHeader, w.Header().Get(TransIDHeader))
    w.Header().Set(RequestTestHeader, req.Header.Get(TransIDHeader))
}

func TestHandleTransactionID(t *testing.T) {
    recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/foo", nil)
    middleware.HandleTransactionID(recorderFunc)(recorder, req)

    if req.Header.Get(RequestTestHeader) == "" {
        t.Error("request header is nil")
    }
    if recorder.Header().Get(WriteTestHeader) == "" {
        t.Error("response header is nil")
    }
    if req.Header.Get(RequestTestHeader) != recorder.Header().Get(WriteTestHeader) {
        t.Errorf("header value mismatch: %s != %s",
            req.Header.Get(RequestTestHeader),
            recorder.Header().Get(WriteTestHeader))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try logging the headers directly in recorderFunc ? `log.Println(req.Header.Get(TransIDHeader), w.Header().Get(TransIDHeader))`

Comment: I *thought* I did that earlier, and it printed the empty string, but I can try again.

Comment: Can you confirm that `TransIDPrefix + tid.String()` is not an empty string because, I was able to print the values when I used hardcoded strings.

Comment: It was when I did a println(), but I'll verify. I've been pulled off on other projects for the time being. Should be back to it this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, `req.Header.Get(RequestTestHeader)` will always remain an empty string because you are not setting the Key as 'RequestTestHeader' in the request header but in the ResponseWriter  `w.Header().Set(RequestTestHeader, req.Header.Get(TransIDHeader))`

On an unrelated note, It would be considered idomatic Go, to have your middleware function signature using the http.Handler interface, `func HandleTransactionID(fn http.Handler) http.Handler`.

Comment: Good catch. I messed that up trying to fix this test due to an unrelated problem. Writing while sleepy is a bad idea. :-/